# There is no programming language

Tags: computer-puzzle, video-games

```
for (GG - U) [
    set color = "0"
    write "cry, sorrow"
]
END

write "game - pleasure?"
loop until "united states = to gather" [
    if "whatweearn = home"
    goto "poco"

]
```

What game am I referencing here?

Comment: Is anything concerning your profile on this site needed to solve this puzzle? (asking because of "goto poco"). If so, you might want to consider somehow making this puzzle self-contained (eg image of your profile picture or copy of your 'About' section) in order for it to still be solvable once you change your profile.

Comment: No,  "poco" is just a replacement for a word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game here referenced is

> [There is no Game: Wrong Dimension](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1240210/There_Is_No_Game_Wrong_Dimension)

The programming language here

> are actually lyrics, referencing the song [My Actual Code](https://genius.com/There-is-no-game-my-actual-code-gigis-song-lyrics), in the game, the song is used and repeated for the player to solve a puzzle using the pseudo-code sang by GiGi (the in-game singer of the aforementioned song)